# Changing a time columne, from a character variable to a time variable in r?

Tags: r

I created a data frame, DF.

```
time <- c("10:00", "11:00", "12:00", "13:00")

temperature <- c("15", "16", "17", "18")

DF <- data.frame(time, temperature)
```

R views the “time” column as a list of characters. How do I get it too recognize the “time” column as a list of times?

I usually use the following code;

```
DF$time <- as.hms(DF$time).
```

However in this case the time column does not include seconds, so that piece of code does not work.

Comment: add the seconds to the timestring: `as.hms(paste0(DF$time,":00")` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste0(time,":00")` to add your precious seconds.